# How to incrementally train H2O naive bayes classifier?

Tags: python, h2o

I need to classify the text docs from elasticsearch using naive bayes classifier.
I experimented on nltk but it doent have support for incremental or stream data handling.
I referred to the below doc

[H2O naive bayes](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3574/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2o.estimators.naive_bayes.H2ONaiveBayesEstimator)

Is it possible to do incremental training with H2O if yes, how? i am also open to use some other classifier which supports incremental mining.

Answer (score 1):

H2O-3 has the option for checkpointing, though not for Naive Bayes. from the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/checkpointing-models.html):

`The checkpoint option is available for DRF, GBM, and Deep Learning algorithms. This allows you to specify a model key associated with a previously trained model. This will build a new model as a continuation of a previously generated model. If this is not specified, then the algorithm will start training a new model instead of continuing building a previous model.`

If this is what you are looking for, the above link also links to python and R code examples on how to use the checkpointing parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Though will have to check if this will be suitable for my case, as the update required will be rather frequent.